# defined parameters but call without any parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

In ionic tutorial, It defined parameter into function and call without any parameters. how does it work?

```
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res;
    return body || {};
  }

  getClassroom(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(apiUrl, httpOptions).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

Comment: They don't call `extractData` in this snippet, it's called by `map`, but from this snippet it's impossible to say what `map` is and what it does.

Comment: `this.extractData` isn’t a call; it’s just a function. You call a function by putting parentheses after it: `this.extractData()`. The function itself is passed as an argument to the `map()` call.

Comment: @zerkms It's very likely a reference to rxjs' [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) function. This looks like Angular code.